# In jquerymobile, how to center icon after resizing it?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, icons

The default size of jqm icon is too small sometimes, so I tried to resize it.

After digging with chrome dev tool, I found out how to do it, but the icons were not positioned well after being applied the following css:

```
<a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-icon-ion-ios7-location-outline ui-btn-icon-notext"></a>

/*icon background*/
.ui-btn {
    font-size: 6rem;
}

/*icon*/
.ui-btn:after {
    font-size: 3rem;
}
```

What else css should I write?

And What if I want to circle the icon background?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-icon-ion-ios7-location-outline ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-big"></a>        
<a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-icon-star ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-big"></a>


/*icon*/
.ui-icon-big:after {
    width: 3rem ;
    height: 3rem ;
    margin-left: -1.5rem;
    margin-top: -1.5rem;
    font-size: 3rem;
    background-size: 2.5rem 2.5rem;   
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/dzf55d7u/)**